# Using stash to set a variable for use across different templates

Tags: stash

If I understand correctly then I should be able to use Stash to set a variable on Template A and then retrieve it on Template B.

Template A contains

```
{exp:stash:set name="testvar" scope="site"}foo{/exp:stash:set}
```

Template B contains

```
Var= {exp:stash:get name="testvar" scope="site"}
```

There is nothing else on these templates but I don't get the value for testvar output on Template B.

Comment: did you try removing the scope=site from the stash:get?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it without the scope parameter and also with scope set to "user"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 2 templates are not being used on the same page (via embed), try saving the stash variable so that it's stored in the database. Set refresh also for how long to store the variable.

```
{exp:stash:set 
    name="testvar" 
    scope="site"
    save="yes"
    refresh="60"
}
    foo
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Comment: That's looking promising actually. Did a quick test and it seems to work but I need to clear my head and test it properly! Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: If you do end up setting variables across the site or for users, it's a great benefit to pair Stash with Mustash to set cache breaking rules and clear the variable from the db at a variety of triggers: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mustash